JSON-serializer not ignoring [SQLite.Ignore]-attribute
I have a property in a class marked with the [SQLite.Ignore]-attribute:
[SQLite.Ignore] public string Name { get; set; }

When I serialize this class to json, the property is missing. When I remove the attribute, its serialized. Seems to me, that Json-serializer is considering this attribute as exclusion.
To exclude properties from serializing, the [JsonIgnore] is used. But in this case, the Json-serializer is also considering the [SQLite.Ignore]-attribute, which is intended for use in SQLite only.
So, the Json-serializer should actually ignore the [SQLite.Ignore]-attribute and serialize the property. Or am I missing something?
Using Newtonsoft.Json 13.03 with c#.

What is the code you are using to serialize to JSON?  Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  E.g. possibly you have some global default settings that are causing properties marked with [SQLite.Ignore] to be ignored.

Also, what SqlLite library are you using?  There are multiple different options mentioned in What is the best way to connect and use a sqlite database from C# and Is there a .NET/C# wrapper for SQLite?, we need to know which you are using to help you.

Thanks for answering. And sorry for asking. While trying to put some lines of code together I found a ContractResolver which was using this [SQLite.Ignore]-attribute. I forgot about this. Question answered.
